# issues with css triangle just around the box

Tags: css

I am using the following code and want to add a triangle either in the css3 format or the image based

here is my css

```
<div id="middleMenu">
  <span class="selected">
    <a href="#" class="text traingle">View Stuff</a>
  </span>
  <span class="text">
    <a href="#">View Gnen</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the css for the above

```
#middleMenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 84px 40%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.traingle {
  background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat;
  top: 31px;
  left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
#middleMenu span.selected {
  background: url(../images/middleMenu.png) repeat;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.text {
  top: 10px;
}
#middleMenu span {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

files added which help generating the arrow key

[image: arrow]

[image: middle menu]

Comment: so .. what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a triangle in CSS like so:

```
#Triangle pointing upwards
.div {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000;
}

#Triangle pointing downwards

.div {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
```

}

jsfiddle.net/dPB75/2

I'm sure you can see where this is going to create one facing left or right.

You can change the size of the triangle by the width of the borders.

Also, you misspelled `triangle`

Comment: Thanks But issue is it is overlapping the other classes and is not rendering properly, even if i provide left and top, i tried using the position, but no avail, could u just try my code and see if i am there

Comment: Yea, this is what your code looks like http://jsfiddle.net/dPB75/. Create a fiddle and send it to me

Comment: i just edited my main question and added two images which help you to create the fiddle and exact example

Comment: Where do you want the triangles

Comment: it should at the bottom and in the middle, but the text of view stuff should be in middle